# how to take rows after a certain criteria SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am using Teradata SQL and have the following data:

| ID | MonthID | Acc | Complaint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202202 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 202203 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 202204 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 202202 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 202203 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 202204 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 202202 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 202203 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 202204 | 3 | 0 |

I want to retrieve all the rows after per ID ever since when Complaint is > 0 ordered by ID, MonthID.

Expected Output:

| ID | MonthID | Acc | Complaint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202202 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 202203 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 202204 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 202203 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 202204 | 2 | 3 |

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Last attempt code:

```
select a.*, 
row_number() over (partition by ID order by Complaint, MonthID) 
from table a
```

Comment: Can you share your last coding attempt at this problem? Maybe it just needs some quick fix. @samronaldo309

Comment: @lemon I have added that in

Comment: Your query assigns a ranking to your current rows, have you though about adding some filtering condition inside a `WHERE` clause, using aggregation functions or something like that?

Comment: @lemon nope, I am bit lost at the moment on how to solve this

Comment: Can you have more than one 0 complaint per id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table expression to compute the initial month per ID. Then filtering out becomes easier. For example:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select id, min(monthid) as mm from t where complaint > 0 group by id
) x on t.id = x.id
where t.monthid >= x.mm
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there another way of doing it. I have huge dataset and feel like it will take a lot of time to process this and I have limited resource (memory)

Comment: @samronaldo309 You can always materialize the subquery into a table, index it by `id`, and then run this query against it. With the index in place it should be fast.

Comment: oh okay, can you please advise me on the syntax to create a temporary table with index?

Comment: @samronaldo309 Unfortunately, I'm not the best person to ask about the nitty-gritty details since I don't have access to a teradata database anymore.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, please see the dataset provided

Answer (score 0):

A simple cumulative sum over complaint codes match you expected result:

```
select *
from tab
qualify
   sum(Complaint) -- inital rows with no complaint get 0
   over (partition by ID 
         order by MonthID
         rows unbounded preceding) > 0
```

If the logic is more complex a CASE might help:

sum(case when Complaint > 0 then 1 else 0 end)